# CSS3 Animation: can't find the mistake (circle path)

Tags: html, css, animation

I can't seem to find the mistake. The letters won't move in a circle path. In Dabblet it works fine but when I run it locally it won't work.

The CSS:

```
         @charset "UTF-8";
@keyframes rot {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-150px)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-150px) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rot {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-150px)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-150px) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rot {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-150px)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-150px) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
}


.smile {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -20px;
    font-size: 100px;
    animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rot 3s infinite linear;

}
.cry {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
}
```

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="smile">S</div>
        <div class="cry">C</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add the webkit prefix too for the transform. (since you are viewing it in chrome, it works in firefox) http://jsfiddle.net/M9Lx8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in dabblet because that site uses prefix FREE, but in jsfiddle, you don't use prefix FREE, so you have to add prefixes for the `transform` appropritately:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rot {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
               translate(-150px)
               rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
               translate(-150px) 
               rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tym37/)

For supportability info of `transform`, check this [CSS transform support](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform). As you can see, looks like just **IE10+** and FireFox 16+ support `transform` without prefix, others should have prefixes added.